# Autostarting Android service upon Application startup

Tags: android, service, startup

Is there a possibility to autostart Service upon starting Application ? The problem is that I am developing separate UI component that depends on service. Ideally this service should be started as soon as hosted application starts. Could this be done via manifest only or could it be done at all ? I know I can start service from my UI component's code, but I want to start service immediatelly after starting main application **even** in case if my UI component hasn`t been created yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `MyApp` class which extends `Application`, and make sure it's declared in your manifest. `MyApp`'s `onCreate()` is then a good place to start the service if you need to.

See [the documentation for the `Application` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).

Comment: I do not have access to the code of the hosted allication. I have access only to common manifest file and my UI component's code.

Comment: @l4004: "I have access only to common manifest file and my UI component's code" -- which is all you need to implement this solution.

Comment: You see, this solution is unacceptable in case if host application has its own custom application. I can not force one to use mine custom app instead... =(

Comment: Yes you can, make your Application extend from the existing one, and amend the manifest to refer to your one.

Comment: The problem is that I will distribute my custom UI component in a jar file. So, generally I will not know the code of a client and thus I will not be able to extend the customer's Application.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the PERMISSION that notifies you of boot completion.  This will allow you to know that the device has started and take action, such as start your service.

```
RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED  Allows an application to receive the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED that is broadcast after the system finishes booting.
```

Comment: Sorry, guys, I do not need a BOOT intents. I am specifically interested in starting application. I need to start service when hosted application starts, not device boots.

Comment: Hmmm ... ok.  When you stated "host application", I thought you had a separate application that you need to interface with.  Besides the answer you accepted was too trivial to think that is what you were looking for.  So, my suggestion was to get your service started at "the beginning of time", before anything else needs the content from the "host application."  Anyway, you can save this in your bag of tricks for the future.